# Applying for jobs in other states

Tags: interviewing, job-search, relocation

I am a new immigrant with technical background and I am currently looking for a job as my first job in US. My problem is that I currently live in a small town in the South, where jobs in my field are scarce, but I am willing to move to anywhere in the country.

My question is, what is the process of getting a job offer from another state or city in the US? Is it acceptable for an employer to do the interview over Skype, or making a visit the place for an interview would absolutely increase the odds of getting the job, in particular for a novice developer?

Comment: If you are near a big city, I'd look into recruiting firms that may be able to help get your foot in the door.  Robert Half International is one such company though I'm sure there are others that may require a bit of networking and Googling to find.

Comment: You are asking "do you think that..." which has attracted a couple close votes under the **Questions seeking advice on what job to take, what skills to learn, etc. are off-topic as the answers are rarely useful to anyone else.** reason. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to avoid closure (not guaranteed it will be closed)?

Comment: @Jim, thanks for your comment and edit. I removed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific process differs by employer.  This answer is marked wiki so anyone can expand the answer.

**Finding a job**

There are a few ways to find a job.  Go do a job search on a jobs website (like dice.com).  You can create a professional profile that describes your experience (such as on linkedin), and join groups on such website where they list jobs.  You can contact a recruiter.  You can go to the website of the company where you want to work and figure out how to apply.  You can contact contacts in your professional network and ask if they know of anything.  You can contact the school from which you graduated and see if they have a job search/placement program.

**recruiters**

If you contact a recruiter, be aware of how they work.  Do you pay them or does the hiring company?  What happens if you find a job and apply to it, then they tell you about it?  Do they require an exclusive deal?  Do they focus on a particular region or a particular field?  Are they okay if you use a different recruiter for a different region or field?  What does the other recruiter/contract say?  Will they modify your resume (they should never do this without your express approval).

**Showing willingness to relocate**

If the job requires relocation, you'll want to be sure that you point out your willingness to relocate.  Some jobs allow people to work remotely, so relocation may not be required.  You'll need to work out the specific details with your prospective employer.

**The Interview Process**

Recruiters like to interview you before sending your resume around.  Good ones will stay in touch with you and prep you for the interview - tell you about positions they found and what the hiring manager is looking for.  They'll ask you how the interview went after it's done, and they'll give you feedback from the hiring manager so you have greater success next time.

The hiring company may want to do a phone interview first.  They may want to do two.  Sometimes three.  These interviews may take 1 to 3 hours, depending upon the company and who you speak to.  They'll often want to do an in-person interview, either at an office near you with people who are qualified to interview you, or by flying someone to you, or by flying you out to meet them.  If they fly you out, you may expect a per diem payment to cover food and incidentals, and they'll pay for the flight.

If they like you but you're not right for the particular position, you may be internally referred within the company and go through the interview process all over again.

**Crossing State Borders**

Travel between the states has no special regulations, but you should be aware that there are a lot of laws that change.  For example, in CA, you have a right to work and a non-compete clause is unenforceable, but it's probably enforceable in the rest of the US.  In the different states, the traffic laws are a little different, so you should familiarize yourself with the local traffic laws.  Same thing for hunting, fishing, and some other activities.

Comment: I tried to find out what "non-compete clause" is in practice, without success. Can anyone clarify please what it actually is?

Comment: A "non-compete" clause is a clause (or section) of an employment contract that is designed to prevent the employee from directly competing with the company during or after employment.  For example, if you worked at Spacely Sprockets, who competes directly with Cogswell Cogs, and signed a non-compete with Spacely, then leave your job under conditions that invoke the non-compete, you may be in breach of contract if you get a job at Cogswell.  The specifics of what would constitute a breach of contract depends upon the particular contract and the particular jobs in question.